# Parsing HTML Data in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, html-parsing

I have an HTML Data which looks like:

```
<div id="foo"><a class="someClass" href="http://somelink">Some Title</a></div>
<div id="foo"><a class="someClass" href="http://somelink1">Some Title 1</a></div>
<div id="foo"><a class="someClass" href="http://somelink2">Some Title 2</a></div>
```

I'm able to show Link title in the tableView, but how can I get URL of these specific title to load a new view (which is pushed through navigation controller upon selecting table cell) ?

Here's the code I'm using to parse HTML Data:

```
HTMLParser * parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData error:&error];
HTMLNode * bodyNode = [parser body];
someArray = [[bodyNode findChildrenWithAttribute:@"id" matchingName:@"someID" allowPartial:NO] retain];
```

And this one to show the array data in the table:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {
    return [someArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }


    HTMLNode* someNode = [someArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[someNode allContents]];     

    return cell;    
}
```

Comment: very valuable question to ask ... i am also waiting for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a node and want information about a child node within it, you have to continue parsing to find the child node and then get the attribute you are looking for. For example:

```
HTMLNode *anchorNode = [someNode findChildTag:@"a"];
NSString *anchorHref = [anchorNode getAttributeNamed:@"href"];
```

It might help to mention that you are looking at [Ben Reeves' HTMLParser](http://benreeves.co.uk/objective-c-hmtl-parser/). (At least I think that is the one you are using).